# А как раньше говорили о температуре за окном? How did people talk about temperature before?

Tags: одним-словом, синонимы

Было ли у русского народа понятие об этой величине или они просто обходились словами «тепло», «прохладно» и т. д.? Ведь «температура» — заморское слово. Интересно, есть ли у него исконно русский если не синоним, то аналог?

---

#### How did people talk about temperature before?

Did Russian people have understanding about that quantity, or they simply managed with words “warm”, “cool” *etc.*? As you know, “temperature” is a foreign, borrowed word. Interestingly, is there indigenously Russian if not synonym, then analogue?

Comment: Мне кажется, больше говорили о явлениях и приметах - метель, ветер, сырость, облачность и т.д., в сочетании с временами года, днями святых и другими знаменательными датами. От примет же и оценивалась погода и прогноз на ближайшие дни. Температура сейчас нужна лишь для того, насколько тепло одеваться, а раньше вопрос выбора одежды не стоял так остро =)

Comment: Я думаю, что до того, как слово _темрература_ вошло в русский язык, говорили просто о _погоде_.  "Как там погода?" "Холодно".

Comment: Давайте меньше думать, но больше подтверждать источниками. ;) Кстати, отвечая, имейте ввиду, что «температура» означает не только обиходное описание погоды, но и конкретную физическую величину — меру хаотичности (по Капице) теплового движения молекул (термодинамическая переменная состояния макроскопической системы). Это значение и в иностранных языках не так давно используется. Скажем, согласно Оксфордскому словарю, оно вошло в английский язык в XVII веке.

Comment: @theUg, а как вы предполагаете, что, отвечая, нужно иметь ввиду меру энтропии. Каким образом вы себе это видите? Что-то типа мера энтропии у древних славян называлась так-то и так-то?

Comment: @shabunc Дык, я о том и говорю, что меры энтропии не было ни и древних славян, ни у древних германцев, ни у кого. Даже латинское слово [temperatura](http://slovari.yandex.ru/temperatura/la/#lingvo/) означало нечто иное (как я понимаю, в современном значении была использована связь с термодинамическим равновесием).

Comment: @theUg аааа, понял)

Comment: Вообще говоря, когда натурфилософы описывали то что мы сейчас называем температурой, они использовали свое личное ощущение тепла и холода предметов и т.д. Гораздо позже было показано, что опустив предварительно руку в холодную воду, а затем ее же в обычную воду, окажется что обычная вода стала "теплой", и следовательно нужно искать какое-то независимое средство оценки теплоты. Так и появились термометры и само понятие температуры. А до этого как раз и было горячо/холодно, тепло/жарко.

Comment: Кстати, температуру можно ввести разными способами, отдельными движениями в истории термодинамики было показать, что они эквивалентны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Греческий корень *термос* (*θερμός*), в таких словах как *термометр*, является родственным английскому *warm* и русским *жар*, *жара*. Они все происходят от [праиндоевропейского](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA) ***ġhu̯ermos*** — «тёплый».

Таким образом, значением слова *термометр* было «измерение теплоты». В этом понимании русские могли использовать слово «жара»: *большая жара*, *небольшая жара*, *сильно жарко*, *не сильно жарко*. Зимой они могли также использовать слово «холод»: *сильно холодно*, *не сильно холодно*. Так, я предполагаю, у них было понятие степеней тепла и холода.

Первый термометр появился в Италии в первой половине XVII века, поэтому до этого русские, также как любые другие народы, не имели возможности точно измерять степень тепла или холода.

---

Greek root *thermos* (*θερμός*), as in *thermometer*, is a cognate to English *warm* and Russian *жар*, *жара*. They all derive from [PIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIE) ***ġhu̯ermos*** — “warm".

Thus the meaning of *thermometer* was “measure of warmth”. In this meaning Russians could use the word “жара” — “heat”: *большая жара*, *небольшая жара*, *сильно жарко*, *не сильно жарко* (high/not high temperature). In the winter they could similarly use the word ”холод”: *сильно холодно*, *не сильно холодно*. So I suppose they had an idea of degree of warmth and an idea of degree of cold.

The first thermometer appeared in Italy during first half of XVII century, so before that time the Russians as well as any other peoples had no possibility to measure degree of warmth or cold precisely.

Comment: I edited the post (currently in moderation queue) by providing translation and some clarification. There are still questions to be addressed, however.

Comment: Not sure that focusing on thermometer is a way to go. I understand the idea of pressing the point that thermometer (i.e., thermoscope with a scale) was the first device for some sort of precise measurement of then obscure concept of “heat”, but this does not address the _temperature_ part of the question. Also, I had changed “degree” to “measure”, because that is what “meter” means. Lastly, I replaced 1613 with more broad time period, because there seems to be disagreement as to when and who exactly slapped the scale on the thermoscope, that debate best be avoided here.